# Finding if there is any letter in a string, and if so, returning false

Tags: javascript

Why does this not work for finding if a string includes a letter and then returning false?
And how can I do it?

```
return pin.includes(/[a-z]/) ? false : true
```

Comment: read the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Answer (score 0):

Because there **includes** takes a string in it's argument.
In your case you can use **match**, or **test**

Example:

```
var regExp = /[a-z]/;
regExp.test('some text'); // return true
```

Example 2:

```
'some text'.match(/[a-z]/);
'123'.match(/[a-z]/); // return null
```

Answer (score 0):

`includes()` doesn't take regex. Try `match()` instead.

```js
let pin = "hello";
console.log(!pin.match(/[a-z]/)); //"!" inverts result to match your logic
pin = "132";
console.log(!pin.match(/[a-z]/));
```

And because the return value from `match()` is truthy or falsy, you don't need the ternary if/else you used in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `String.prototype.match(regex)` function.

```js
const reg = /[a-zA-Z]/

const func = (s) => !s.match(reg);

console.log(func("465496464[][]"));
console.log(func("4464644aa423164646"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex test method. Test method tests for a match in a string and it returns true if it finds a match and false otherwise.

```js
const pin = 'abc123';
const ret = !/[a-zA-Z]/g.test(pin);
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var r = new RegExp(“[a-zA-Z]”);
return r.test(pin);
```

With “pin” being a string variable.